# Pass commandline arguments argv using devenv (C++) in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, command-line-arguments, devenv

I'm trying to use devenv to pass commandline arguments (argv) for my C++ code. (VS2013)

FOr example,

> myEXE.exe -log "c:\logs\inside\a.txt" -i - compplete - list

if i use VS solution, I can pass CMD line arguments **"-i - compplete - list"** 
using

> "Right click Project -> select Debugging -> Command ARguments"

FOr devenv I give thi sin my VS native CMD prompt:

```
devenv myEXE.exe
```

**HOw do i pass the CMD line args (argv= -i - compplete - list) here for debuggging ?**

Comment: I question was how do i pass CMD line arguments of my EXE. devenv /debugEXE myEXE.EXE. Now how do I pass argv of myEXE.exe ?

Comment: yes, this is he answer. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want run your product? you just do:

```
myEXE.exe -i - compplete - list
```

I suppose, devenv is the compile tool.

Comment: `devenv` is the Visual Studio IDE. `cl` is the Microsoft Visual C/C++ Compiler and `link` is the linker.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wrong. I suppose devenv is related to solution. There is the document.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx.I hope it's useful to you.